# Три точки вместо текста на кнопке

Tags: text, button, java

Написал калькулятор на java и...О боже вот скрин:
[image]
Из-за чего это?

Comment: `button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));`

Comment: Дайте кнопкам больше места, ваш текст не влезает. А вообще, Swing ужасен, а Java имхо малопригодна для десктопных приложений.

Comment: @VladD тем не менее есть примеры хороших десктопных приложений на Java. Например продукты от JetBrains.

Comment: @a_gura: Есть, и за это глубокий респект их разработчикам.